# suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable defined on a measurable set $E$. Prove the following inequality.

Tags: measure-theory

$\int_E \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n \leq \int_E \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$

This problem appears in a textbook.  Is this a typo?

Also, I don't know whether the sequence of functions converges, or whether it is dominated by a function.  How can this be solved?

Comment: Look up "Fatou's inequality".

Comment: Yes, but don't I need the sequence to conv. ptwise a.e. to use Fatou's lemma?

Comment: No, the limit inf is always well defined.

Comment: Both sides of the inequality are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can define $g_n=inf\{f_k:k\ge n\}$ then every $g_n$ is nonnegative, $\{g_n\}$ is an increasing sequence  and $\lim_n g_n=\lim \inf f_n$ as n goes to infinity and then you can apply the monotone convergence theorem.